# Term equality in Isabelle

Tags: equality, relation, isabelle

Is there already some **term equality** relation defined in Isabelle? What is the broadest set of terms on which it is defined?

Just to be clear, I'm looking for a relation  a ~ b that returns True iff a **is** b in the sense that they look exactly the same written down: no properties of a and b should need to be known to evaluate a ~ b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No such thing exists. There's no notion of syntactic equality in the logic, because it admits definitions (`x ≡ T`) and substitution (`x ≡ y ⇒ P x ≡ P y`).

What you could do instead is use ML's equality operator on terms. But for that, you have to use `ML` blocks.

Comment: I don't quite understand why definitions (x ~ T) and substitution are bad?

Comment: They aren't "bad". They prevent definition of a syntactic term equality relation as you described it.

Comment: Oh I see: definitions and substitutions are universally allowed in Isabelle, making it impossible to define term equality.